# How to add increasing numbers in front of a list items/objects when outputting them?

Tags: c#, list, oop

i have a list of objects. I would now like to out put the list but also add numbers in front like this...

1] item[0]

2] item[1]

3] item[2]

i have this function

```
        private void ListAnimals()
        {
            foreach (var pet in _petslist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pet);
            }
        }
```

then i'm calling that function like this

```
 public void Play()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have these pets in your list...");
            ListAnimals();
            Console.WriteLine("Which pet would you like to play with?");
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

            switch (input)
            {
                case "pet1":
                    _petslist[0].Interact();
                    break;

                case "pet2":
                    _petslist[1].Interact();
                    break;

                case "pet3":
                    _petslist[2].Interact();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("You do not own that pet, please try again");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

My question, can i somehow display numbers in front of list items in my ListAnimals() function so i can use that number in switch statement instead to actual pet name? I have tried to override ToString() in my animal class, i have tried with padding and also tried adding an array of numbers and use for loop to output numbers in the array and list items close to each other.

Comment: Either use a for loop instead of foreach to get the list index, or do `foreach ((i, pet) in petslist.Select(var (i, pet) => (i, pet))`. And then `Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}] {pet}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
foreach (var pet in _petslist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pet);
}
```

do

```
for (int i = 0; i < _petslist.Count; i++)
{
    var pet = _petslist[i];
    Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}] {pet}");
}
```

Also, instead of a `switch` statement afterward, you should just read the integer value into `input`, then use that directly:

```
_petslist[input - 1].Interact();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display numbers easily if you use a `for` loop:

```
private void ListAnimals()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < _petslist.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + 1 + "] " + _petslist[i]);
    }
}
```